# How to render combo box text insenstive?

Tags: python, combobox, gtk2

A rather brief question: 

 How would I make text within a combo box insensitive/diabled, using pygtk (**not** GTK3)?

Comment: This one shows no prior research at all (ref: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306049/3001761)

Comment: You may have done, but *the question doesn't show it*.

Comment: I agree with @jonrsharpe. If the answer did not work, then you should clarify your question further. Also, your question states "using pygtk (not GTK3)" and that's what the answer was based on, but in your comment you say that you are looking for Gtk3.

Comment: @AlastorMoody Oh yeah... lol - I got mixed up when I looked at this question ;D

Answer (score 2):

There is a method:

```
combo.disable_activate()
```

that will disable the activate signal on the entry widget in the combo box.

you can find more information on the reference at http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkcombo.html